# Edit view using php after create view on structure -> views in drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views

I created a new view in drupal 7 on the menu `structure->views`, with table format .

But I want to try to add php script on table columns, how can i do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and enable views_php module in modules section of drupal. After enabling you can use global php field in views and then add your php code for a specific field.

Thanks

Comment: its work, but how do I call his field ?? i try `<?php echo $row->Sid ; } ? >` Not show

Comment: you must have the particular field above the php code. And then you can use placeholders to access the fields above this php field

Comment: how do I know the name of the field is in view ? I was a little trouble with Postgres , because I am more familiar with MySQL .

Comment: what id you want to print, if you want the row counter you can use result counter field in views

Comment: I want to make (if) from the value of an existing field , but I try to make a query by calling the field according to the database but the data does not appear ,

Comment: not clear about your requirement. but you need two fields, first one which you need to query in the second php field. You can make the first field "exclude from display"

Comment: Can you give an example take a query from the database with php ? I tried but failed to hold